# Update Query if data of 2 columns is equal to a particular string

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My table contains user query data. I generate a hashed string by doing the following:

```
queries = Query.objects.values('id', 'name')

# creating a bytes string using the ID, NAME columns and a string "yes" (this string could be anything, I've considered yes as an example)
data = (str(query['id']) + str(query['name']) + "yes").encode()

link_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', data, b"satisfaction", 100000)
link_hash_string = binascii.hexlify(link_hash).decode()
```

I've sent this hashstring via email embedded in a link which is checked when the use visits that link. My current method of checking if the hash (got from the GET parameter in the link) matches with some data in the table is like this:

```
queries = Query.objects.values('id', 'name')

# I've set replyHash as a string here as an example, it is generated by the code written above, but the hash will be got from the GET parameter in the link
replyHash = "269e1b3de97b10cd28126209860391938a829ef23b2f674f79c1436fd1ea38e4"

#Currently iterating through all the queries and checking each of the query
for query in queries:
    data = (str(query['id']) + str(query['name']) + "yes").encode()
    link_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', data, b"satisfaction", 100000)
    link_hash_string = binascii.hexlify(link_hash).decode()
    if replyHash == link_hash_string:            
        print("It exists, valid hash")
        query['name'] = "BooBoo"
        query.save()
        break
```

The problem with this approach is that if I have a large table with thousands of rows, this method will take a lot of time. Is there an approach using annotation or aggregation or something else which will perform the same action in less time?

Comment: can your add a new column with your hash value and do filter by it?

Comment: @BearBrown Yes that I can do that but I don't know if it is better to create an entire new column for the hash or use aggregation/annotation. Could you please tell me?

Comment: Put the username in the link as well. Then get the data from the table for that user, calculate the hash, and see if matches the hash string from the link.

Comment: @Barmar Yes that reduces the complexity but consider the case where the user has thousands of queries. The operation will still take time.

Comment: I was thinking this was something like a password-reset application, where there's just one row per user.

Comment: Does the table have a primary key that you can put into the URL?

Comment: The whole point of `pbkdf2` is to be computationally expensive and take a long time. Is your goal to prevent people from brute-forcing hashes by submitting lots of different inputs? If that's the case, you can use Bear Brown's suggestion and hash the input from the user as it comes in, and then compare it to the hashes in the database.

Comment: @Barmar Yes it has a primary key (The ID) but I was avoiding putting the primary key in the link for security concerns. If no efficient solution exists, I'll go with that only.

Comment: The only real alternative is to put the hash into the table and index that column.

Comment: If you put the ID and hash into the URL, that mitigates the security concern. Someone can guess the ID, but they shouldn't be able to guess the corresponding hash easily.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Yes I'm aware that the point of `pbkdf2` is to be computationally expensive, thats why I was looking for an efficient Queryset method which does aggregation. yes, my motive is to block brute force attacks. It seems that the solution is to add the primary key to the link as Barmar suggested.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I will do as you suggested and put the id as well as the hash in the link. So, should I accept that no such aggregation method exists as of now? If yes please post your suggestion as a solution so that I can accept it as the answer

Comment: @hulkinBrain Ok, sorry, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida No issues mate, valid doubt :D